# Duplicate elements in a mongo db collection

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

Is there an quick efficient way to duplicate elements in a mongo db collections based on a property. In the example below, I am trying to duplicate the elements based on a jobId.
I am using Spring boot, so any example using Spring boot API would be even more helpful.

Original Collection

```
{ _id: 1, jobId: 1, product: "A"},
{ _id: 2, jobId: 1, product: "B"},
{ _id: 3, jobId: 1, product: "C"},
```

After duplication

```
{ _id: 1, jobId: 1, product: "A"},
{ _id: 2, jobId: 1, product: "B"},
{ _id: 3, jobId: 1, product: "C"},
{ _id: 4, jobId: 2, product: "A"},
{ _id: 5, jobId: 2, product: "B"},
{ _id: 6, jobId: 2, product: "C"},
```

Comment: There is no automatic way. You have to write a find method with your criteria and create new objects with the result(without the id field) and save again

Comment: @pvpkiran I think you're wrong. Aggregation Framework is able to handle such issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following aggregation:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            values: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            size: { $size: "$values" },
            range: { $range: [ 0, 3 ] }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$range"
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$values"
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: { $add: [ "$values._id", { $multiply: [ "$range", "$size" ] } ] },
            jobId: { $add: [ "$values.jobId", "$range" ] },
            product: "$values.product",
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            _id: 1
        }
    },
    {
        $out: "outCollection"
    }
])
```

The algorithm is quite simple here: we want to iterate over two sets:

- first one defined by all items from your source collection (that's why I'm grouping by null)
- second one defined artificially by [$range](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/range/index.html) operator. It will define how many times we want to multiply our collection (3 times in this example)

Double unwind generates as much documents as we need. Then the formula for each _id is following: `_id = _id + range * size`. Last step is just to redirect the aggregation output to your collection.

Comment: Thanks for your code. But, I am not sure if I understood how it could work if I want to duplicate based on the jobId. In my example, after the duplication, I end up with jobId 1 and 2. Say, if I want to now duplicate just items with Job id 2, how can I do that. Also, I don' know we could assume all items for same JobId will be ordered

Comment: @user320587 I've modified my answer so that now jobId will be 1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3 just as you expect. If you want to copy only one particular item you should add match as a first aggregation stage like: { $match: { "_id": 2 } } and this code will still be working fine.